# Android Retrofit's @Path don't work. Why?

Tags: android, api, path, retrofit

I have an app which takes trivia question from api and display. When I use the actual link for take questions it works *(https://trivia.willfry.co.uk/api/questions?categories=movies&limit=16 )* .  However when I add path for categories, app does not work.

This is work :

```
@GET("questions?categories=general_knowledge&limit=16")
Call<List<Questions>> general();
```

However this is not work :

```
@GET("questions?categories={type}&limit=16")
Call<List<Questions>> getData(@Path("type") String type);
```

Also when I delete the app from emulator, and install again with path include method, it works just once.  Not second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`categories` is not a path parameter, it's a query, do this instead

```
@GET("questions?limit=16")
Call<List<Questions>> getData(@Query("categories") String categories);
```

and about the second problem you mentioned, there's noting in the provided code to find out from

Comment: You're welcome mate. Path parameters are the ones. in the path (they always appear before `?`) and query params are the one after `?` separated by `&`